# Avoid repetition in JSON file

Tags: json

I am not familiar with JSON object and I want to use them with Python . I have a JSON object like this

```html
{
"a" : {"value" : 20200212, "conversion":"{"fun":["strptime"], "module":["datetime"], "extra_args":["%Y%m%d]} },
"b" : {"value":"something here"},
"c" : {"value" : 20211121,"conversion":{"fun":["strptime"], "module":["datetime"], "extra_args":["%Y%m%d]} }
}
```

My question is it possible to not repeat this in this file?

```html
{"fun":["strptime"], "module":["datetime"], "extra_args":["%Y%m%d]}
```

Comment: JSON is just a format, you cannot use variables-like links, sorry. You must repeat your line each time you want to use it

Comment: Thanks for your response